# Next JS 14 Routing

Tags: next.js, app-route

Assume I have a file structure as this (I am using app routing with Next 14),
`app->[id]->test-[slug]`

Assume I didn't set the base path.
Now assume I want to set the base path as '/test'. In that case, my folder structure will be,
`app->[slug]`

So as you can see now I can't have url like,
`localhost:3000/1/test/abc` as it will be like, `localhost:3000/test/abc`.

Is there any way I can test my app by adding the [id] to the url with the base path `/test`?
That means I want url to be like `localhost:3000/1/test/abc` even after setting the basepath. I went through the documentation but didn't find a way, or maybe it is not possible. Any ideas on this>